# Why does sqlalchmy func return strings instead of integer?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

We have a postgresql database with a stored procedure that returns a SETOF a type with this definition:

```
Column |  Type   | Modifiers
-------+---------+----------
my_id  | integer |
```

However, when I execute the function like this:

```
 for result in session.query(func.get_my_thing(someval)):
     print(result)
```

It gives me results like this:

```
('(8968)',)
```

Yeah, that's a tuple of strings that look kind of like a single element tuple. It's definitely a string, i.e. `print(type(result[0]))` shows that it's of type `str`.

Why does it return this string type instead of the integer that the function returns?

Answer (score 0):

I'm partway to an answer. Looking at the emitted SQL it's the difference between:

```
SELECT get_my_thing(someval)
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM get_my_thing(someval)
```

The former is what's emitted by

```
session.query(func.get_my_thing(someval))
```

I'm not sure how to emit the latter SQL

Comment: Create an [alias](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.alias) from the function and follow the instructions on using it in `select_from`. The example is specifically for postgresql.